# (History Of) Best Practices for ASP.NET MVC Internationalization

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, internationalization, webforms

I'm trying to fully understand this topic, and I don't believe I can do so unless I also understand the history of recommendations in addition to the current recommendation.

My brief outline of this history is below, and I'd like to know if it is basically correct?

1. ASP.NET 1.1 recommended the use of Satellite Assemblies and the ResourceManager class
2. [ASP.NET 2.0 switched to a recommendation to use .resource files](http://drdobbs.com/windows/188700729) (not loaded in a DLL) and to access them via HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject

   - Satellite assemblies were still being generated, but they were created invisibly at run-time.
   - The "GetGlobalResourceObject" did the work of checking the HTTP header culture information for you, while also picking the resource.
3. [ASP.NET MVC, with it's emphasis on testability, reverted back to satellite assemblies / ResourceManager class as the primary recommendation](http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2009/07/16/resource-files-and-asp-net-mvc-projects.aspx) for accessing I18N resources.

   - Having Satellite assemblies generated during ASP.NET run-time is incompatable with a unit test framework trying to access the resources.
   - Using ResourceManager requires a hair more work for the developer (because they must write code to check session, cookie, or HTTP header info for the culture), but is also more flexable precisely because (1) it allows for culture to be selected by more than just HTTP headers and (2) allows unit tests to easily dictate which culture is in use.

What important details or caveats have I omitted from the above summary?  Is my MVC commentary still considered "current" for MVC3 (and MVC4)?

Answer (score 1):

**A brief history of Asp.Net MVC framework**

ASP.Net MVC is a new Framework built on the top of Microsoft .Net Framework to develop web application. This framework implements the MVC pattern which helps to provides separation of code and also provide better support for test-driven development (TDD).
Asp.Net MVC is a lightweight and highly testable open source framework for building highly scalable and well designed web applications. Here is the list of released version history of ASP.NET MVC Framework with theirs features.

**Asp.Net MVC1**
Released on Mar 13, 2009

Runs on .Net 3.5 and with Visual Studio 2008 & Visual Studio 2008
    SP1
 MVC Pattern architecture with WebForm Engine
 Html
    Helpers
 Ajax helpers
 Routing
 Unit Testing
    **Asp.Net MVC2**
 Released on Mar 10, 2010
 Runs on .Net 3.5, 4.0 and with Visual Studio 2008 & 2010
 Strongly typed
    HTML helpers means lambda expression based Html Helpers
    Templated Helpers
 Support for Data Annotations Attribute
    Client-side validation
 UI helpers with automatic scaffolding &
    customizable templates
 Attribute-based model validation on both
    client and server
 Overriding the HTTP Method Verb including
    GET, PUT, POST, and DELETE
 Areas for partitioning a large
    applications into modules
 Asynchronous controllers

**Asp.Net MVC3**
Released on Jan 13, 2011
Runs on .Net 4.0 and with Visual Studio 2010
The Razor view engine
Improved Support for Data Annotations
Remote Validation
Compare Attribute
Sessionless Controller
Child Action Output Caching
Dependency Resolver
Entity Framework Code First support
Partial-page output caching
ViewBag dynamic property for passing data from controller to view
Global Action Filters
Better JavaScript support with unobtrusive JavaScript, jQuery Validation, and JSON binding
Use of NuGet to deliver software and manage dependencies throughout the platform
Good Intellisense support for Razor into Visual Studio
**Asp.Net MVC4**
Released on Aug 15, 2012
Runs on .Net 4.0, 4.5 and with Visual Studio 2010SP1 & Visual Studio 2012
ASP.NET Web API
Enhancements to default project templates
Mobile project template using jQuery Mobile
Display Modes
Task support for Asynchronous Controllers
Bundling and minification
Support for the Windows Azure SDK
**Asp.Net MVC5**
Released on 17 October 2013
Runs on .Net 4.5, 4.5.1 and with Visual Studio 2013
One Asp.Net
Asp.Net Identity
ASP.NET Scaffolding
Authentication filters - run prior to authorization filters in the ASP.NET MVC pipeline
Bootstrap in the MVC template
ASP.NET Web API2

Credit To: Mr. Shailendra Chauhan

Answer (score 0):

One big advantage of satellite assembly is that you don't have to re-build your application for introducing a new language. You can create satellite assembly for a new language and drop it in the application and ResourceManager will automatically load it based on the culture

If you use .resource files, you have rebuild the entire application and have to do another deploy.